# Can't convert from string to Joda LocalTime with DefaultFormattingConversionService

Tags: java, spring, jodatime, data-conversion

Am unable to convert string to Joda LocalTime with [`DefaultFormattingConversionService`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/format/support/DefaultFormattingConversionService.html).

If I pass time as "12:00" it says time is too short, but if I pass it as "12:00:00", it says it is malformed.

```
import org.joda.time.LocalTime;
import org.springframework.format.support.DefaultFormattingConversionService;

public class SpringLocalTimeFormatterTry {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

      DefaultFormattingConversionService service = new DefaultFormattingConversionService();
      try {
         System.out.println(service.convert("12:00", LocalTime.class));
      }
      catch (Exception e) {
         System.out.println(e.getMessage());
      }
      try {
         System.out.println(service.convert("12:00:00", LocalTime.class));
      }
      catch (Exception e) {
         System.out.println(e.getMessage());
      }


   }
}
```

How to use it correctly or fix?

Comment: If you provide some of your code it would be easier to see what the problem is. Are you using a constructor for `LocalTime` or are you using a parser of some sort? It's hard to tell.

Comment: Why are you using `DefaultFormattingConversionService`? Would `LocalTime.parse("12:00");` not be sufficient?

Comment: @mohammedkhan the code is above it is SSCCE. I am using `DefaultFormattingConversionService` because it is prerequisite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The vanilla settings of `DefaultFormattingConversionService` use platform default locale, which, I assume from the error, are the same as mine, ie. English. That means, that for time you need to add the AM/PM indicator. This works for me:

```
System.out.println(service.convert("10:12 am", LocalTime.class));

>> 10:12:00.000
```

To handle your desired time format, you can add an extra converter:

```
service.addConverter(new Converter<String, LocalTime>() {
    @Override
    public LocalTime convert(String source) {
        return LocalTime.parse(source);
    }
});
```

Then, both examples pass:

```
System.out.println(service.convert("12:00", LocalTime.class));
>> 12:00:00.000
System.out.println(service.convert("12:00:00", LocalTime.class));
>> 12:00:00.000
```

You can skip registering the default converters by creating the service with

```
new DefaultFormattingConversionService(false);
```

Finally, I assume in the production code you are actually getting the `ConversionService` from the `ConversionServiceFactoryBean`, so you can configure that as follows:

```
@Bean
public ConversionServiceFactoryBean conversionService() {
    ConversionServiceFactoryBean conversionServiceFactoryBean = new ConversionServiceFactoryBean();
    Set<Converter<?, ?>> myConverters = new HashSet<>();
    myConverters.add(new Converter<String, LocalTime>() {
        @Override
        public LocalTime convert(String source) {
            return LocalTime.parse(source);
        }
    });
    conversionServiceFactoryBean.setConverters(myConverters);
    return conversionServiceFactoryBean;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("HH:mm:ss");
LocalTime localTime = dtf.parseLocalTime("12:00:00");
System.out.println("Time"+localTime);
```

Comment: In this instance she's trying to parse just time rather than a date, so `DateTime` isn't the right one to use here.